# TypeError: string indices must be integers?

Tags: python

I'm trying to eventually print 'board' but the console will not get past this part of the code:

```
board1=(" ")
board2=(" ")
board3=(" ")
board4=(" ")
board5=(" ")
board6=(" ")
board7=(" ")
board8=(" ")
board9=(" ")



board= ((board1+" | "+board2+" | "+board3)
["---------"]
(board4+" | "+board5+" | "+board6)
["---------"]
(board7+" | "+board8+" | "+board9))
```

It just returns this error code. Anyone have any ideas?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jaymeson\Desktop\Rock Paper Scissors CPU.py", line 36, in     <module>
    ["---------"]
TypeError: string indices must be integers
>>>
```

I would like the output to be:

```
  |   |  
---------
  |   |  
---------
  |   |
```

Comment: What is it you're *expecting* `["---------"]` to do?

Comment: What do you expect `["---------"]` to *do* in this expression? What is the expected output?

Comment: Note that you could do this much more easily with a list of `boardN` characters and either `str.format` or `str.join`.

Answer (score 2):

`(board1+" | "+board2+" | "+board3)` creates a string. You then ask Python to index that string with `string[...]`. Strings only can take integers (the position of the individual characters). You gave it the string `"---------"` instead.

If you wanted to draw lines between the cells, don't use `[...]` around those. Just concatenate (and include a newline):

```
board= ((board1+" | "+board2+" | "+board3) + 
        "\n---------\n" +
        (board4+" | "+board5+" | "+board6) +
        "\n---------\n" +
        (board7+" | "+board8+" | "+board9))
```

I'd use a nested list instead, and do the printing later:

```
board = [[' ' for _ in range(3)] for _ in range(3)]

def print_board(board):
    print(*(' | '.join(row) for row in board),
          sep='\n--+---+--\n')
```

Now you have a 3 x 3 matrix in nested lists, and can alter cells as needed:

```
>>> def print_board(board):
...     print(*(' | '.join(row) for row in board),
...           sep='\n--+---+--\n')
...
>>> board = [[' ' for _ in range(3)] for _ in range(3)]
>>> print_board(board)
  |   |
--+---+--
  |   |
--+---+--
  |   |
>>> board[0][0] = 'O'
>>> board[1][1] = 'X'
>>> print_board(board)
O |   |
--+---+--
  | X |
--+---+--
  |   |
```